# What is the measure of $ \overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{NPB}$ in the figure below?

Tags: geometry

For reference: From an external point $P$ the circle draws the tangents
perpendiculars $PA$ and $PB$. Then the $\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{PMN}$ secant is drawn so that $ \overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{AN} = 2\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{AM}$. Calculate $ \overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{NPB}$

My progress:
I made the drawing and put the angles that I was able to demonstrate. If I can demonstrate that $\measuredangle PBM =\theta$ the problem ends

[image]

Comment: According to the angles that you have labeled, isn't $APBO$ a rectangle (and hence a square)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\measuredangle PBM+\measuredangle MBO=90^\circ\\ \measuredangle  PBM=90^\circ-\measuredangle MBO=90^\circ-(45^\circ+\theta/2)=45^\circ-\theta/2$$
The way to solve this is to show $\triangle PAN$is isosceles. Then $AN=AP=R$. Then $\triangle AON$ is equilateral. $2\theta=60$. $\measuredangle NPB=90^\circ-30^\circ/2=75^\circ$

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

Say $PN$ intersects $AO$ at point $T$. Then can you see that $AM = MP = MT$?

Now as $M$ is the midpoint of $PT$, if perp from $M$ to $AO$ is $MH$ then

$MH = \frac{PA}{2} = \frac{R}{2} ~ $ ($R$ being the radius of the circle)

As $MH$ is half of $OM$ in right angled triangle $\triangle OHM$, $~ \theta = \frac{\pi}{6}$

Comment: $M$ being the midpoint of $PT$, you can also say that $OM = MB = OB = R$.

Comment: you are welcome